# How to delete screen datablock

Tags: 3d-view

Is there any way yet to delete screen datablocks in outliner ? I have a couple of temp screens from my old startup file that freeze 2.75.

Comment: do you mean the scenes?

Comment: Welcome Frank :) This site is not a forum, please start with the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour and get your first badge ;)

Answer (score 1):

To delete one or several [screen layouts](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/interface/screens.html?highlight=screen) you should use Info window:

[image]

Here the same technique as for [deleting images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-do-i-completely-remove-an-image-from-my-blend-file) is used, i.e with <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed click [image] button near the screen layout name to delete it completely from the .blend (it will disappear after reboot).

To delete many layouts, it may be easier to [delete all of them](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/clearing-screen-layout-list) except for one.

Comment: Yes thanks I know that way but if I try as soon as I hit the X Blender just freezes. The mouse still moves but nothing will work..except Crl+Q. Even if I Ctrl +left or right arrow and get to one it will freeze. The old way with the script isn't ideal. Just have to be careful.

Comment: As I've got you have this problem only with several ("temp ones") screen layouts. If 2.75 version lags like this, delete them from 2.74 and save it with `Ctrl`+`U`, just to be sure.

Comment: Good Morning its just 7am here. I was going to try your first idea (sounds logical) however then your second idea popped up and got me thinking/confused. Would you care to elaborate on exactly how to do that. I would like to keep the setup of all my "good" screens and not have to redo the others. Thanks much for your time. Sorry guess I haven't got how posting here works yet. My first try at it.

Comment: Also you can try to use `bpy.data.screens['BrokenScreen'].user_clear()` and reload the file.

Comment: 'BrokenScreen'  should be the name of screen to delete with no quotes ?  My earlier reference to your second idea was to one that has been deleted it seems. Also 2.74 wouldn't delete "temp.001-full" either.

Comment: Please disregard first first part of above. After using the "user_clear" method the screens in question showed the no user 0 next to them in the pulldown but after both just closing or Ctrl+U and closing they were still there went opened again.

Comment: Waited too long to edit my last comment. In the outliner there are six different temp files but only three show in the pulldown. I'll try deleting all that are listed and see if that works. Thanks again.

Comment: No luck. Seems I recall this being a problem for some time now. I couldn't delete them but I could just Ctrl+right arrow through my screens arrangement without Blender freezing. Had read there had been work done the outliner and was hoping I could do it that way.

Comment: Upload your problem .blend to [pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) and give a link here. I don't get what "temp.001-full" should delete 2.74. You might want to read some info about organizing your startup.blend and UI layouts

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to go to the *Outliner* and choose the *Data API* sub-editor, then untwirl the *Screens* and search for and check  *Runtime Data* checkbox for the screens that you want to delete.

After this, save the file and reload and it’ll be cleaned.